# Scrolling Scene Background - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My title might have actually been a bit misworded, as to be honest I'm not sure how to word it, but basically I'm making a game on Unity and I have my main scene and I am making a main menu however what I want to do is have a, I guess, camera slowly panning around the main scene as the background of the main menu. Not sure if I worded that right or what wording to actually type into Google to research it so I'm hoping you guys might be able to point me in the right direction.

Cheers guys,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

As stromdotcom mentioned you can attach a script to the camera.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do but if you want to circle the camera around a point...

Try making an empty game object in the middle of your scene and point the camera at it.

Make the object the parent of the camera (using the object and cameras transform properties).

From here you should be able to set the game object to rotate using a script, which should make the camera spin as it is a child of the object.

I have not tried this in Unity but I have used this technique in other programs so I'm assuming it will work. Sorry if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If your scene is already set up then you can attach a script to your camera which simply modifies the camera's transform to move it around the room.  You can move and rotate the camera just like any other transform in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure what you are looking for is "Animation view". Unity has a tutorial on it: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animation-view?playlist=17099